# Process remains in the RabbitMQ server consumer list after network failure

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I'm trying to simulate a scenario where I connect to a message queue and than after network failure (in my case disconnecting from VPN) my process tries to reconnect to a message queue in an infinite while loop.

Here is my code that seems to be working what I intended to do, but the problem is that after disconnecting from VPN this process remains in the list of consumers on 'my_queue' and upon reconnecting to the VPN a new consumer is created so they pile up. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
import pika
import time

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print("Message received.")

while True:
    try:            
        cred = pika.PlainCredentials('my_user', 'my_pass')
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='192.168.10.171', port=5672, virtual_host='/', credentials=cred, heartbeat_interval=20, socket_timeout=1))
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.queue_declare(queue='my_queue', durable=True)
        channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='my_queue', no_ack=True)
        print('Connected.')
        channel.start_consuming()
    except:
        print('Lost connection.')
        time.sleep(2)
```

This is how it looks like on the server. Only the last consumer is actually active, but the messages are being distributed to every one of them.
[image: Consumer list on 'my_queue']

Comment: How long have you waited for them to disappear? Eventually the heartbeat will time out and RabbitMQ will detect the client is gone.

Comment: It has been a couple of hours now actually. As you can see a have set a heartbeat_interval to 20 (meaning 20 seconds I suppose). I expected the consumers to disappear from this list after that interval is exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the heartbeat interval on the server was set to zero, so the inactive consumers were not being detected. I was using pika version 0.11.0. which seemingly took heartbeat proposal from the server side.